# Displaying floating point without integer part when number between 0 and 1

Tags: ios, floating-point, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I want to display floating point number in iOS like .23

I have seen questions where people do not want fractional part. But I didn't find answer for this. Can I do it with NSNumberFormatter? I tried to set min and max number of integer digits but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: After converting the number to a string, check if the string starts with `0`. If so, take the substring from index 1.

Comment: Can you tell me any number between 0 and 1 having Integer part greater than 0? Excluding 1.0000000.

Comment: Hi maddy, that is a solution but I have to write  a function but I am using number formatter class. Thanks for the solution!!!

Comment: @anoop-vaidya I am sorry but I don't get how it is relevant to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way, i think, is to use NSNumberFormatter:

```
NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##.00"];
NSString* result = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.63f]];;
```